# Show same stuff on external screen as my screen

Tags: display

When I'm lecturing I want the exact same stuff that shows on my MacBook Air's screen to show on the external screen. How do I do that?

For just slides the regular settings are fine, but when I'm coding/compiling/debugging live they are a hassle like no other.

(Ps. would like suggestions for better titles/tags in the comments. Or if your rep is high enough just go ahead and modify whatever you'd like.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the OS you are using but in general in the display preferences (System Preferences → Display) you should look for a **mirroring** option.

Screenshot for Mountain Lion:

[image]

Comment: Mountain Lion- thanks. This stuff is too easy on a Mac.